# how to plot time series with x axis ticks in month-year format in ggplot

Tags: r

How to plot the data below in `ggplot` with x axis to show ticks in format as 'Jan-99'.

My data is as below:

```
head(rates,10)

    Month Repo_Rate
1  Apr-01      9.00
2  May-01      8.75
3  Jun-01      8.50
4  Jul-01      8.50
5  Aug-01      8.50
6  Sep-01      8.50
7  Oct-01      8.50
8  Nov-01      8.50
9  Dec-01      8.50
10 Jan-02      8.50

sapply(rates,class)

#  Month   Repo_Rate 
# "character"   "numeric"
```

I have done the plotting  using `xts`/`zoo`/`ts` packages but would like to do using `ggplot` as this gives my publication quality figures.

Comment: Well first thing you nedd to do is convert your character vector to date format... see `?as.Date`, and perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242955/converting-year-and-month-to-a-date-in-r. Then plotting should be straight forward. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458822/create-specific-date-range-in-ggplot2-scale-x-date , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576095/formatting-dates-with-scale-x-date-in-ggplot2, and lots more examples on SO

Comment: Can you check the update by @G.Grothendieck on your previous post with `ggplot`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following:

```
rates$date <- as.character(rates$month, stringAsFactors = FALSE)
rates$date <- as.Date(rates$date, "%B-%d") 

# Now plot the graph #######

ggplot(rates)+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y= Repo_Rate))+
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%B-%d))
```

In any case if you need to change the date format please refer to :  "http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html"